# No signal to monitor after uninstallation of display driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, vga, sony-vaio

I was on the Sony website trying to get the latest display driver for my Sony VAIO laptop. Their instructions told me to uninstall my display driver through add/remove programs in the control panel and to reboot then visit the website and install the latest driver.

Easier said than done, after the uninstall my laptop won't display on the monitor anymore. (My 5yr old dropped my laptop and broke the screen 2 months ago, so I've been using a monitor to display the image ever since.) Even in safe mode the monitor gets no image, although after pressing f8 repeatedly I do hear the windows start up sound.

My model number is VPCCW21FX the video card is NVIDIA GeForce 310 M and my OS is Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I just want to know how to display the image on my monitor so I can install the latest driver and finish the process but I can't see anything since it's broken.

Comment: Do you see the BIOS screen? The driver should only affect the OS.

Comment: The external monitor isn't showing anything just stuck in power save mode.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to boot into safe mode and reinstall your drivers.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/start-computer-safe-mode

Failing this, you should still see an image at boot time - you can trigger a system restore which will get you up and working again.
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/668-system-recovery-options.html

Comment: I still see no image in safe mode.

Comment: looks like youllneed to plug in an external monitor then if your laptop is capable of it.

Comment: That's what I've been using. But since I uninstalled this display driver now the external monitor shows no image. I'm using a VGA not even in safe mode still no image.

Comment: Got the computer to start up normally instead of safe mode, but still same problem . The external monitor is stuck in power save mode . I can't see the screen so installing the driver update is out of the question. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have no screen - how do you know its booted correctly? I think your best choice at this point is to remot desktop to your laptop from another machine and install the drivers.

Comment: I hear the windows sound when it starts up

Comment: you can try a LiveCD - http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-recovery.html  This might allow you to run a system restore and reactivate the drivers

Comment: After hours of research online (pretty stressed out now) pressing fn + f7 twice to activate the external monitor doesn't even work, although I've played with my laptop enough that when I power it on I now hear the window noise like normal AND when it finishes starting up I hear the beeping sound as normal only problem is now that my external monitor shows no image like before .